# Map a String as Primary Key in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm developing a project where I have a class called Conductor (Driver, in spanish). This Conductor class has a parameter LatLng (containing a position latitude-longitude). I want these two classes to persist them in my database using Hibernate, with which I have some experience.

Here you are the classes with their hiberate's mapping files:

```
public class LatLng implements Serializable {


/*
 * Atributos
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -234127535402360915L;

private long id;
private double latitud;
private double longitud;

/*
 * Métodos
 */
public LatLng(){

}

public LatLng(double latitud, double longitud){
    this.latitud = latitud;
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getLatitud() {
    return this.latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(double value) {
    this.latitud = value;
}

public double getLongitud() {
    return this.longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(double value) {
    this.longitud = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Latitud: " + this.latitud + ", longitud: " + this.longitud;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result;
    result = (int) (id + latitud + longitud);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(other==null)
        return false;

    if( !(other instanceof Conductor) )
        return false;

    LatLng pos = (LatLng) other;

    return pos.getId()==this.id && pos.getLatitud()==this.latitud && pos.getLongitud()==this.longitud;

}
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE 
hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

```
<class name="com.ingartek.cavwebapp.model.LatLng" table="LATLNG">

    <id name="id" type="long" column="LATLNG_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="latitud" type="double" column="LATLNG_LATITUD" not-null="true" />
    <property name="longitud" type="double" column="LATLNG_LONGITUD" not-null="true" />

</class>
```

```
public class Conductor implements Serializable {

/*
 * Atributos
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4492787316635472774L;

private String email;
private String nombre;
private String telefono;
private String domicilio;
private LatLng domicilioCoord;

/*
 * Métodos
 */
public Conductor(){

}

public Conductor(String email, String nombre, String telefono, String domicilio,
        LatLng domicilioCoord){

}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String value) {
    this.nombre = value;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String value) {
    this.email = value;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return this.telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String value) {
    this.telefono = value;
}

public String getDomicilio() {
    return this.domicilio;
}

public void setDomicilio(String value) {
    this.domicilio = value;
}

public LatLng getDomicilioCoord() {
    return this.domicilioCoord;
}

public void setDomicilioCoord(LatLng value) {
    this.domicilioCoord = value;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return email.hashCode() + nombre.hashCode() + telefono.hashCode() + domicilio.hashCode() + domicilioCoord.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if(other==null)
        return false;

    if( !(other instanceof Conductor) )
        return false;

    Conductor c = (Conductor) other;

    return c.getEmail().equals(this.email) 
            && c.getNombre().equals(this.nombre)
            && c.getTelefono().equals(this.telefono)
            && c.getDomicilio().equals(this.domicilio)
            && c.getDomicilioCoord().equals(this.domicilioCoord);
}
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"Hibernate Mapping 3.0" 
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
```

```
<class name="com.ingartek.cavwebapp.model.Conductor" table="CONDUCTORES">

    <!-- Las clases referenciadas no se habían creado -->

    <id name="email" type="text" column="CONDUCTORES_EMAIL">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="nombre" type="string" column="CONDUCTORES_NOMBRE" not-null="true" />
    <property name="telefono" type="string" column="CONDUCTORES_TELEFONO" not-null="true" />
    <property name="domicilio" type="string" column="CONDUCTORES_DOMICILIO" not-null="true" />

    <!-- Clases referenciadas -->
    <many-to-one name="domicilioCoord" column="CONDUCTORES_DOCIMILIOCOORD" class="com.ingartek.cavwebapp.model.LatLng" cascade="remove" />

</class>
```

The problem arises when, in the Dao class, I perform this operation:

public Conductor anadirConductor(String pEmail, String pNombre, String pTfno,
             String pDomicilio, double pLat, double pLon) throws ExisteConductorException {
        System.out.println("Creando nuevo conductor");

```
    if(!isEmailUsado(pEmail)){
        beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Creando el conductor");
        LatLng pos = new LatLng(pLat, pLon);
        System.out.println("El identificador de la posicion es " + pos.getId());
        Conductor unConductor = new Conductor(pEmail, pNombre, pTfno, pDomicilio, pos);

        if(!flota.existeConductor(unConductor)){
            flota.anadirConductor(unConductor);
        }

        session.save(pos);
        session.save(unConductor);
        commitTransaction();
        return unConductor;     
    }else{
        rollbackTransaction();
        throw new ExisteConductorException();
    }
}
```

... using this line Conductor c = new PtDaoService().anadirConductor(email, nombre, tfno, domicilio, lat, lon); an Exception is caught throwing the following message:

```
feb 17, 2015 1:05:40 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
```

GRAVE:  org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.ingartek.cavwebapp.model.Conductor
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)....

Which is my error?

Need help :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The constructor I was using in my Dao was not assigning anything...

It should have been that way:

```
public Conductor(String email, String nombre, String telefono, String domicilio,
        LatLng domicilioCoord){
    this.email = email;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.domicilio = domicilio;
    this.domicilioCoord = domicilioCoord;
}
```

Comment: Assigned means hibernate will understand that, while saving any object hibernate is not responsible to create any primary key value for the current inserting object, user has to take the response.This is the default generator class used by the hibernate, if we do not specify <generator –> element under id element then hibernate by default assumes it as “assigned” If generator class is assigned, then the you are responsible for assigning the primary key value to object which is going to save into the database.

Comment: Since in your hbm file you've written 
 <id name="email" type="text" column="CONDUCTORES_EMAIL">
        <generator class="assigned" />
 </id>
and you were not manually assigning value for primary key hence you were getting that exception.